# Cannot cd into a directory, no visible problem

Tags: linux, shell

I've tried searching and couldn't find a similar scenario.

I have a directory into which I cannot `cd`:

```
# cd /var/log
# cd apache2
bash: cd: apache2: No such file or directory
# ll -d apache2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Jun 15 12:58 apache2/
# echo $EUID
0
# lsof | awk '$NF ~ /log\/apache2/'
# mount | grep apache
#
```

I'm at wits' end to how to check that directory. Any suggestion as to what's going on? And what should I do to regain access to that directory?

---

**EDIT:**

```
# stat apache2
  File: `apache2'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 16h/22d Inode: 21665       Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-06-15 12:58:54.542248000 +0700
Modify: 2015-06-15 12:58:54.542248000 +0700
Change: 2015-06-15 12:58:54.542248000 +0700
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Can you try to `cd` into this directory using a different shell? I also have no idea what may be going on here. EDIT: ACL maybe?

Comment: I would try and run a filesystem check on that partition/filesystem before proceeding.

Comment: One more question: can you list contents of this directory? Or maybe is the entire `/var/log` directory mounted as an external filesystem?

Comment: I had such an effect once with a corrupted filesystem.

Comment: I think adding `stat /var/log/apache2` output would be useful

Comment: What filesystem is that? I am a bit surprised about the size 0 of that directory.

Comment: @Esref `stat` output added

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I can't. I got `ls: cannot open directory apache2: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Anthon and @Janis makes sense. I'll try to arrange an `fsck`

Answer (score 1):

probably there is a white space in the end of apache2. Try

```
cd /var/log/apache2*
```

if it's ok, then go to an upper dir and rename the apache2 like:

```
cd /
mv /var/log/apache2* /var/log/apache2
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Still get same error message.

Comment: If that where the case, the output from `ll` would have had a space between `apache2` and the `/` (that indicates it is a directory).

Comment: okay then, let's see the flags with `lsattr /var/log/apache2`
and then SELINUX (just in case)
`getenforce `
and
`ls -Z /var/log`